# Python NetworkX two dimensional list of all neighbor neighbors

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am trying to do something that feels forced with networkx but there must be a way.  I just don't see the right process in the networkx documentation or google searches.
Given

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
test={'first':['a','b','c'],'next':['b','c','d']}
dftest = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(dftest,'first','next')
```

I want to return a 2 column list showing not just the edge relationships, but all connections regardless of nodes in between.  That list would look like the below where ',' delimits the list columns and each bullet is a row.

- a,b
- b,c
- c,d
- a,c
- a,d
- b,c
- b,d

I'm then going to append an inversion of this so a filter of column 1 for a node returns all neighbors regardless of whether they are 'next door' or a neighbor of my neighbor.

Any thoughts on how to do the above with networkx or another network/graph python package

Comment: It sounds like you just want the [connected components](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) in your graph.  If you really need all node pairs in each connected component, then use `itertools.combinations(cc, 2)` for each component node set.

Comment: Note: what you're asking for results in a list that has O(N^2) elements,  which means things will quickly get out of control for just modestly sized graphs.  You should think about whether you really need to enumerate the node pairs explicitly, or whether you can just maintain the connected component sets.

Comment: the proper implementation of this would indeed be with a graph DB, but to keep costs down I'm trying to see if I can make it work with an existing RDMBS table for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving my own question after further research.  The below code does it.  Welcome suggestions on a more efficient way to do this.

```
dfNodes = pd.DataFrame()
i=0
for node in G.nodes():
    if (i==0):
        dfNode = pd.DataFrame(nx.descendants(G,node))
        dfNode['first']=node
        dfNode.columns.values[0] = "next"
        dfNodes =dfNode
    else:
        dfNode = pd.DataFrame(nx.descendants(G,node))
        dfNode['first']=node
        dfNode.columns.values[0] = "next"
        dfNodes = pd.concat([dfNodes,dfNode])
    new_row = {'first': node, 'next': node}
    dfNodes.loc[len(dfNodes.index)] = new_row
    i=i+1
dfNodes.sort_values(['first','next'])
```